# Are polymer tantalum capacitors safe for use in new designs?

Tags: capacitor, tantalum

I want to expand this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/99320/are-tantalum-capacitors-safe-for-use-in-new-designs) to cover **polymer** tantalum caps.  In my application I have an older switching regulator that outputs 24V and needs large output capacitance (220uf), so ceramic or polymer aluminum caps are not an option.  I have to remove the MnO2 tantalum caps and I'm thinking of using polymer tantalum caps.
Kemet's papers seem to indicate that these caps would be a better alternative to the regular tantalum caps.  They don't have the same failure rates and do not present the ignition failure.  Has anybody seen any other issues with this type of caps?

Comment: Why exactly are polymer aluminum capacitors not an option? Space?

Comment: The voltage ratings for the polymer aluminum ones don't go as high.  I believe most of them are 16V max

Comment: I'm using Nichicon 35V solid polymer caps in a couple of new designs. Not cheap, but very good performance. http://nichicon-us.com/english/products/pdfs/e-cv.pdf

Comment: I was thinking of the D cases such as the ECAS family from Murata.  I do have a height restriction of about 8mm.